# Dart doesn't append lists of Future

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to call Future.await on two lists of Future:

```
Future<void> first() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print('first');
}

Future<void> second() async {
  print('second');
}

void main() async {
  final list1 = [0, 1].map((e) => first()).toList();
  final list2 = [2, 3].map((e) => second()).toList();
  final appended = list1.addAll(list2); // result is not defined
  // await Future.wait(appended); // <= error: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
  await Future.wait([...list1, ...list2]); // <= this works
}
```

Why `addAll` not working as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list1.addAll(list2)` *mutates* `list1`.  It does not return a new `List` nor does it return the original `List`.  It returns nothing, which is why the analyzer gave you an error that `appended` has type `void`.  Don't ignore warnings and errors.  If you get unexpected results, double-check the documentation to verify your expectations.  The [`List.addAll` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/addAll.html) shows that it has a `void` return type, and it shows example usage.

Note that when you later do `Future.wait([...list1, ...list2])`, you therefore are including the `Future`s from `list2` twice (although aside from being slightly less efficient, it shouldn't affect behavior).

If you want a new `List` instead, you can use [`List.operator +`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/operator_plus.html):

```dart
var appended = list1 + list2;
```